# yii2-widget, Select2 and taggest support

Tags: php, yii, jquery-select2, yii-extensions, yii2

Can i use taggest support with dats only from model? i don't need new tags creating by user

```
echo '<label class="control-label">Tag Content</label>';
echo Select2::widget([
'name' => 'color_1', 
'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a color ...', 'class'=>'form-control'],
'pluginOptions' => [
    'tags' => ["red", "green", "blue", "orange", "white", "black", "purple", "cyan",            "teal"],
    'maximumInputLength' => 10
],
```

]);

Now user can add tags like "gr","r" and other, but i don't want it. I only need tags creating by my model (like stackoverflow)

Comment: I mean this widget [link](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2)

Comment: Use dropdown..or autocomplete widgets!!

Comment: so it's autocomplete)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your _form.php

```
echo '<label class="control-label">Tag Content</label>';
echo Select2::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'tags',
    'name' => 'tags',
    'data' => common\models\Tag::getOptions(),
    'options' => [
        'placeholder' => 'Select a color ...',
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'multiple' => true
    ], ]);
```

then add following code in your model

```
public static function getOptions(){
    $data=  static::find()->all();
   $value=(count($data)==0)? [''=>'']: \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($data, 'id','name'); //id = your ID model, name = your caption

    return $value;
}
```